# C#: How to initialize an object and all it's attributes

Tags: c#, oop

Is there any way in C# to initialize an object without the need of initializing his attributes to use them?

I find myself mapping json objects in to classes and I wonder if it's inefficiento to do stuff like this:

```
Class1 object1 = new Class1 ();
object1 .Name = new Class2 ();
object1 .Name.Content = "name";
```

I don't want to use initializers for code clarity to avoid stuff like:

```
Class1 obj1 = new Class1 ()
{
    Name = new Class2()
    {
        Content = "name"
    }              
 };
```

This looks fine, but the models I have to work with are usually big and with many layers and ends up beeing a bit of an unreadeable cluster if I use initializers.

I can not change the models I recieve so simplifying the models is not an option either.

Is there any way were I can do something like:

```
Class1 object1 = new Class1 ();
object1.Name.Content = "name";
```

That automatically implement `Name = new Class2()` implicitly?

Allowing me to avoid the Name is not initialized exception. I know I can do my own constructors and initialize it's attributes in them, but there's already a LOT of code done and it's not feasble anymore to do this.

And if is not possible, I am interested in any alternative ways that could help me to reduce some code initializing attributes.

Comment: Doesn't your json library handle this?

Comment: `Name = new Class2()` - you can do that in the constructor of `Class1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't implicitly instantiate a property, no. It must be instantiated *somewhere*.

What you *could* do, to enable the syntax you're wanting, is instantiate it within the `Class1` constructor or in the property declaration. For example:

```
public class Class1
{
  public Class2 Name { get; set; } = new Class2();
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZySMLX

or

```
public class Class1
{
  public Class2 Name { get; set; }

  public Class1()
  {
    this.Name = new Class2();
  }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sbd2wP

But obviously this has its own side-effects - I don't know if you want to force that to be *always* instantiated in this way, or if there are scenarios in your application where that wouldn't be desirable.

---

P.S. You said this situation arose because you were

> mapping json objects in to classes

...but surely this is something that should be done by an automated serialisation library, rather than writing all these instantiations out in literals. It's not clear precisely what the scenario was. I've answered your question directly, but  I would potentially question whether this is actually the best approach to your overall problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't use an automated serialization library because I get an example of a JSON for a webpage, and I have to generate that JSON with the coresponding data to be shown on the page. This JSON is from a diferent project and honestly I never thought about the possibility of importing this JSON in to my project and use it to generate the classes, I may try that on the future. And some times I may not want the entire object to be initialized, I was hoping maybe for a different way to call the constructor or something like that to do so.